# How can I get Android Marketplace to recognize my updates?

Tags: android, google-play

I updated my Android app, and uploaded it to the Android Marketplace, increasing the VersionCode and VersionName in my manifest file.  But it never shows up on my HTC Droid Incredible as there being an update available.  Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Did you click the "Save" button on the upload page?

Answer (score 1):

No, you've taken the correct steps. If you just uploaded it to the market place. And checked right after. You wont see that there has been an update. As it takes time to work through the system to each device. Especially considering all the other many applications with updates.

Give it some time and it should go through.

Comment: As i had this issue before and soon realized it takes some time.